# php script not selecting my $_POST field

Tags: php, select, post, menu

I have a working version of the following script, however there is a huge block of hardcoded data to make it work. In the following code I have shortened that code to just an associative array, however in my page the value of SiteTypeID is always 0, when it should be a number between 3 and 43. The $_POST['SiteTypeID'] doesn't seem to be selecting anything. I can't find the error.

Here is the code of the page, the section that I need help with is commented.

```
<?php
$page_title = 'Edit Your Account';
include ('includes/header.html');
include ('includes/functions.php');
include ('includes/config.inc.php');
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} elseif (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
    include ('includes/footer.html');
    exit();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['UserID'])){
require (MYSQL);
echo '<div class="text">';
$scrubbed = array_map('spam_scrubber', $_POST);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if (filter_var($scrubbed['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
        $url = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $scrubbed['url']);
    } else {
        $url = "";
        echo '<p class="error">Please enter a valid url</p>';
    }
if (!empty($scrubbed['SiteTypeID'])){
        $sitetypeid = $scrubbed['SiteTypeID'];
    } else {
        $sitetypeid ="";
        echo '<p class="error">Please select a category</p>';
    }
if($url && $sitetypeid){
    $q = "SELECT UserID, url, SiteID FROM sites WHERE url='$url' AND SiteTypeID='$sitetypeid' AND SiteTypeID!=$id";
    $query = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
        $q = "UPDATE sites SET url='$url', SiteTypeID='$sitetypeid' WHERE SiteID=$id LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1){
            echo '<p><b>Your url has been successfully edited</b></p>';
            } elseif (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 0){
                echo '<p>No new details have been inserted</p>';
            } else {
            echo '<p class="error">The user could not be edited due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>'; // Public message.
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br />Query: ' . $q . '</p>'; // Debugging message.
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p><b>That url has already been registered with that category, if you own this site you can change categories if you wish to. Please note that a website cannot be added multiple times in different categories.</b></p>';
        }

    }
}

?>
<h1>Edit Your Sites</h1><p><b>Do not add duplicate urls, they will be deleted. We only accept family-safe urls. We play fair and expect our members to do the same.</b> </p>
<?php 
$query2 = "SELECT s.SiteTypeID, u.UserID, s.SiteType FROM sitetypes AS s LEFT JOIN sites AS u USING (SiteTypeID) WHERE SiteID=$id";
$mx = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($mx) ==1){
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($mx, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo '<p>Your site\'s current category is <b>'.$row2['SiteType'] . '</b></p>';
}
?>
```

//This is the block of code where the problem is.

```
<?php
$optionarray = array(3 => 'Children & Family', 4 => 'Home Business', 5 => 'Advertising', 6 => 'Affiliate Programs', 7 => 'Art & Photography', 9 => 'Beauty & Jewelry', 10 => 'Blogging', 11 => 'Books, Literature', 12 => 'Business & Finance', 13 => 'Computer Games', 14 => 'Computing', 15 => 'Dating & Relationships', 16 => 'Directories', 17 => 'Education', 
18 => 'Electronics', 19 => 'Entertainment', 20 => 'Environment', 21 => 'Flowers', 22 => 'Food, Drink', 23 => 'Forums, chat rooms', 24 => 'Free Stuff', 25 => 'Gifts & Shopping', 
26 => 'Health', 27 => 'Humor', 28 => 'Interior Design', 29 => 'Internet Marketing', 30 => 'Miscellaneous', 31 => 'Music', 32 => 'Pets', 33 => 'Real Estate', 34 => 'Religion & Spirituality', 35 => 'Science', 36 => 'Sports', 37 => 'Stocks & Trading', 38 => 'Travel', 39 => 'Vehicles', 40 => 'Web Design', 41 => 'Web Hosting', 42 => 'Work At Home', 43 => 'Psychology');
echo '<form action="edit_your_sites.php" method="post"><select name="SiteTypeID"><option value="">Select a Category</option>';
foreach ($optionarray as $key => $value){
    echo '<option value="$key"';
    if (isset($_POST['SiteTypeID']) && ($_POST['SiteTypeID'] == "$key")) echo 'selected="selected">';

    echo '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

// end block of problematic code.

```
<?php


$ms = "SELECT UserID, url, SiteID FROM sites WHERE SiteID=$id";
$msp = mysqli_query($dbc, $ms);
if (mysqli_num_rows($msp) > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($msp, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo '<p>Url:<input type="text" name="url" size="60" maxlength="80" value="' . $row['url'] .'" /><small>You can only add each url once into the database, each url must be unique.</small></p><p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Site Information!" /><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear Form" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" />
</form><p><a href="delete_url.php?id=' . $row['SiteID'] . '"><b>Delete Url</b></a>';
} else {
    echo '<p class="error">A system error occurred, we apologize for the inconvenience.</p>';
}
?>
<?php
} else {
    $url = BASE_URL . 'index.php';
    header("Location: $url");
}
echo '</div>';
include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: Show the relevant HTML markup and the output of `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: When I output print_r($_POST) it says that the post array is empty, but I still don't know how to fix it. the relevant html is inside the page in echo statements, there is a header file which is html but that doesn't affect the functioning of this script.

Comment: Are you posting to the correct file? You would need to inspect the form that sends you to this page. I assume this is a page that you get to after filling some sort of form. Inspect the methods and action in that form.

Comment: yes I am posting to the correct file, the problem is that my $key variable in the foreach loop is not telling $_POST to use the number that is associated with the $key. The $key should tell post to make the SiteTypeID a number, instead it is always 0. Maybe the selected="selected" part is badly coded or something, I'm new at this so I can't see the error. I tried debugging techniques but I can't find the error.

Comment: Well for starters it should be $_POST['SiteTypeID'] == $key), not $_POST['SiteTypeID'] == "$key"). You are checking against a string as opposed to the $key variable so take out the quotes around $key. Also, your selected syntax doesn't need the ending ">" so you should echo 'selected = "selected"' only. That's it for syntax, I will give this another look to see if I can see anything else.

Comment: @Charles No, he is cheking against variable here  $_POST['SiteTypeID'] == "$key".